# Update mongocharpdriver nuget

Tags: c#, mongodb, nuget

There is CSharp driver for MongoDb - [mongocsharpdriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver) that is marked as legacy in nuget feed and it still getting updates (latest version 2.11). My project is referencing very old version of mongocsharpdriver and should be updated. Do I need to update legacy driver to latest version or completely remove it and use new one - [MongoDB.Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver)?

Comment: This is an interesting question as I know the legacy driver uses the `MongoDB.Driver` internally to do most of its work but keeps the old-style API. I guess when it was created they were planning on deprecating it .

Comment: @KevinSmith you mean I can just update my driver without code changes?

Comment: It'll require code changed going to `mongocsharpdriver` to `MongoDB.Driver`, I can't imagine they're that bad changes though, but depends on your usage and your test coverage over it to prove you've not broken anything.